# Subcategory for every parent category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I'm trying to do in wordpress, menu where every parent category will have a subcategories, but i want to show subcategories only when parent category is active?

I want to do sth like this:

```
<ul>
     <li class="active">Category 1</li>
          <ul>
               <li>Subcategory 1</li>
               <li>Subcategory 2</li>
          </u>
     <li>Category 2</li>
     <li>Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

My menu should looks like:

```
in index:

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

in current category page:

- Category 1
   - Subcategory 1
   - Subcategory 2
   - Subcategory 3
- Category 2
- Category 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

Here is the code you can use:

```
$args = array(
  'option_none_value'  => '-1',
  'orderby'            => 'ID',
  'order'              => 'ASC',
  'show_count'         => 0,
  'hide_empty'         => 1,
  'child_of'           => 0,
  'echo'               => 0,
  'selected'           => 0,
  'hierarchical'       => 1,
  'name'               => 'cat',
  'class'              => 'postform',
  'depth'              => 0,
  'tab_index'          => 0,
  'taxonomy'           => 'category',
  'hide_if_empty'      => false,
  'value_field'      => 'term_id',
); 

 echo wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

[Reference URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories).

Comment: Thanks, where should i paste it? i Have menu in sidebar and show it by: {<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'navbar-list', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>}

Comment: I checked it. It isn't what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If you could send either a screen shot or copy the actual HTML I could probably help you with some CSS that would do what you are trying to achieve.

(Right click the menu -> Click Inspect, so that we can see the HTML)

I was able to achieve this with a Woocommerce sidebar menu by adding the following CSS

```
/* Hide all Sub Categories */
ul.product-categories li.cat-parent ul.children {
    display: none;
}

/* Show Sub Categories when the parent is active */
ul.product-categories li.cat-parent.current-cat ul.children {
    display: block;
}
```